# How to store response values into an array and read it in response body of another request using index values

Tags: arrays, jmeter

I want to store the IDs of each set in an array and later I want to read each value in the array using index values in JMeter. Can someone please help me how can I achieve this?

response of the 1st request is in the below format:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "vulns":     [
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "82003",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696056"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "90067",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696057"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "70000",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696058"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "70032",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696059"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "90042",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696060"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to pass the IDs of the above request in the 2nd request's body as below:

Request Body:

```
{"data":[{"id":"ID1"},{"id":"ID2"}]}
```

where ID1 and ID2 are read from an array that stores all the IDs from the 1st request's response

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).vulns.ID.collect { id -> ['id': id] }

   def payload = ["data": ids]

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```

   It will extract all the `ID` elements values and transform them according to your needs
3. In the next request refer the generated JSON as `${payload}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)